# using Enumerable.Aggregate on System.Collection.Generic.Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, generics

Say that i have a [generic dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3eayzh46.aspx) with data like this (I hope the notation is clear here):

{
   "param1" => "value1",
   "param2" => "value2",
   "param3" => "value3"
}

I'm trying to use the [Enumerable.Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx) function to fold over each entry in the dictionary and output something like this:

"/param1= value1; /param2=value2; /param3=value3"

If I were aggregating a list, this would be easy. With the dictionary, I'm getting tripped up by the key/value pairs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need `Aggregate`:

```
String.Join("; ", 
    dic.Select(x => String.Format("/{0}={1}", x.Key, x.Value)).ToArray())
```

If you really want to use it:

```
dic.Aggregate("", (acc, item) => (acc == "" ? "" : acc + "; ") 
                        + String.Format("/{0}={1}", item.Key, item.Value))
```

Or:

```
dic.Aggregate("", 
     (acc, item) => String.Format("{0}; /{1}={2}", acc, item.Key, item.Value), 
     result => result == "" ? "" : result.Substring(2));
```

Comment: Thanks!  looking at the dic.aggregate code, I see why the String.Join solution is better suited for this.

Comment: But isn't the `String.Join` method walking over the dictionary twice (once for setting up the array and a second time to join array elements)? You are also creating a throw-away array when you can just as well join your string as you are walking over the elements.

Comment: paracycle: If performance is at the forefront, you should probably use something like `StringBuilder` in a loop but even if it's not, using `Join` will allocate a single string buffer and copies all the strings in the array to it which is probably more efficient than concatenating each part of string and throwing it away. The concat operation in aggregate is O(n^2) where n is the length of output string.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this suits your needs:

```
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string> {{"a", "alpha"}, {"b", "bravo"}, {"c", "charlie"}};
        var actual = dictionary.Aggregate("", (s, kv) => string.Format("{0}/{1}={2}; ", s, kv.Key, kv.Value));
        Assert.AreEqual("/a=alpha; /b=bravo; /c=charlie; ", actual);
```

Comment: That would leave you with an extra ";" at the end though. Most of the time (and also for the original question, it seems) that is not desirable.

Comment: Will include an additional "; " you'll have to strip off. Works anyway.

Comment: You can use the result selector to take care of that trailing entry:

var actual = dictionary.Aggregate("", (s, kv) => string.Format("{0}/{1}={2}; ", s, kv.Key, kv.Value), s => s.TrimEnd(' ').TrimEnd(';'));

Comment: neontapir: It's pretty easy to get rid of the it but I wouldn't use `TrimEnd(';')`. It'll screw things up if the last value ends with `;` character.

Comment: neontapir, If you are looking for a moral victory, yours is the solution that I ended up using.  The ';' character was actually a mistake in my original question: I didn't actually need the ';' character to delimit the key-value pairs, I just needed whitespace.    

Still, whether I actually needed it or not, the ';' character was part of my question, and in this situation, I've gotta give the score to Mehrdad.  Thanks!

Comment: @brad: Thanks! 
@Mehrdad, I concur. If the data might have semicolons, something more stringent is required. My point simply was that there is an overload to Aggregate() that allows for some post-processing.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
var str = dic.Aggregate("", (acc, item) => {
    if (acc != "")
        acc += "; ";

    acc += "/" + item.Key + "=" + item.Value;

    return acc;
});
```

Comment: That's what you get for changing from simple lambda syntax to a function body at the last minute. :)